# iOS app Cannot connect to Metamask by using WalletConnect protocol

Tags: metamask, walletconnect, ios

I am using WalletConnectSwift Sdk to connect to MetaMask app and Trust wallet.
But I can rarely see the connection permission popup from MetaMask. Once connect successfully and back to our dapp, I see connection failed from WalletConnect delegate. How can I overcome this issue? Any suggestion or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Note that latest iOS made it really buggy to connect from `wss://` websocket bridge relay. Use the `HTTP` version of the bridge relay. Also when your Dapp is on the web, iOS needs the url to be `HTTPS` for the relay to work.

This might be the case with your Dapp, check once.